# Testing NSURLConnection requests performance with XCTestCase

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, nsurlconnection, xctest

I'd like to take advantage of the testing classes and methods in Xcode to measure the performance of several asynchronous HTTP services requests my app does. I call services by means of an object that makes use of an `NSURLConnection` connection and implements the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol to get the responses. I've been reading the [Testing with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/conceptual/testing_with_xcode/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH1-SW1) document, and a way to test asynchronous operations is described, but it doesn't fit this kind of asynchronous task, since a protocol delegate is involved.

I don't find any example/tutorial of how could I write test methods for these cases, or for cases where asynchronous operations involve protocol methods in general. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1

Thanks